# about eclipse plugin marker filter configuration

Tags: view, configuration, filter, marker

I made eclipse plugin and it has marker view.
the view  has 'configuration contents' which is marker filter configuration.
in the filter configuration, 'show all items' are checked by default, but I want to uncheck this option and to check my customized option.
how  could do this? please help!! 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Because the internal bits are not exported, it is very impractical to implement this in code, but you can use some obscure configuration tricks to inject a "user-defined" problems pane filter into your custom problems view.

1. Create a custom marker view (http://web.archive.org/web/20141018022849/https://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008_11_01_archive.html). Record your view ID.
2. If you don't already have one, create a "preferenceCustomization" element in your product definition in plugin.xml.

   ```
   <extension id="product" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
     <product application="com.example.product.application" name="App">
       <property name="appName" value="My App"/>
       <property name="preferenceCustomization" value="plugin_customization.ini"/>
       <property name="applicationXMI" value="com.example.product.application/Application.e4xmi"/>
       <property name="applicationCSS" value="platform:/plugin/com.example.product.application.branding/css/default.css"/>
     </product>
   </extension>
   ```
3. Add the following key to your plugin_customization.ini file (assuming view ID is "com.example.product.application.view.problems". The key should look like it is unnaturally smooshed together, and the whole thing should be on one line):

   ```
   org.eclipse.ui.ide/org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.CachedMarkerBuildercom.example.product.application.view.problems=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><prefs markerLimitEnabled="false"><filterGroup scope="3" enabled="true"></filterGroup></prefs>
   ```
4. Modify the entry based on desired traits.

- *markerLimitEnabled* is "true" if you would like a number limit to apply to the number of markers, or "false" otherwise.
- *markerLimit* sets the maximum number of markers to show. It is ignored if *markerLimitEnabled* is false.
- *scope* sets which resources' problems, based on current selection, will be displayed. This is an integer.

  - A value of 0 (zero) will show all problems from all workspace resources.
  - A value of 1 (one) will show problems for the selected resource.
  - A value of 2 (two) will show problems for the selected resource and its descendants.
  - A value of 3 (three) will show problems for all resources within the selected resources' projects.
  - A value of 4 (four) will show problems for all resources within the current working set.
- *enabled* is "true" if you wish it to apply to the problems pane by default. "false" if you do not wish this.
  Child elements of filterGroup elements are useful for specifying which columns to display, and (possibly) their column widths, but I have not delved into this aspect.

For more information, check out the Eclipse source code of MarkerFieldFilterGroup (especially loadSettings()) and MarkerContentGenerator (especially loadFilterSettings()).